# Transition in navigation drawer android

Tags: android, animation, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

Anyone having idea that how to achieve this type of transition. When we open `Navagation` drawer full screen is getting animation like this. I also looked at [reside menu](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu) but here menu is predefined not as i want.

I also tried with `NavigationDrawer` but not got succeed.

```
   drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            float moveFactor = (linearLayout.getWidth() * slideOffset);

            float min = 0.9f;
            float max = 1.0f;
            float scaleFactor = (max - ((max - min) * slideOffset));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            {
                linearLayout.setTranslationX(moveFactor);
                linearLayout.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
                linearLayout.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
            }
            else
            {
                AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);


                TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(lastTranslate, moveFactor, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                anim.setDuration(0);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                animSet.addAnimation(anim);
                ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(1.15f, 1.0f, 1.15f, 1.0f);
                scale.setDuration(10);
                scale.setFillAfter(true);
                animSet.addAnimation(scale);

                drawerView.startAnimation(animSet);

                lastTranslate = moveFactor;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

        }
    });
```

**Thanks in advance**

[image: Animation in navigation drawer]

Comment: you could have changed the predefined menu in Reside-Menu Library to what ever view you wanted

Comment: any idea how to achieve that???

Comment: You mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335300/moving-and-resizing-drawerlayouts-content-on-sliding

Comment: @MikeM. exactly I was looking something like that. let me check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I got my answer through this [link for original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335300/moving-and-resizing-drawerlayouts-content-on-sliding). Please have a look here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="test.pyramidions.com.dynamicview2.MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and for `MainActivity.java` please have a look below

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public TabsPagerAdapter tabsPagerAdapter;
public static ViewPager pager;
int Numboftabs = 2;
Toolbar toolbar;
public NavigationView navigationView;
public DrawerLayout drawer;
View holderView, contentView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    holderView = findViewById(R.id.holder);
    contentView = findViewById(R.id.content);
    tabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Numboftabs);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(new DrawerArrowDrawable(this));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                             @Override
                                             public void onClick(View v) {
                                                 if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(navigationView)) {
                                                     drawer.closeDrawer(navigationView);
                                                 } else {
                                                     drawer.openDrawer(navigationView);
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         }
    );


    drawer.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onDrawerSlide(View drawer, float slideOffset) {


                                     contentView.setX(navigationView.getWidth() * slideOffset);
                                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                                             (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) contentView.getLayoutParams();
                                     lp.height = drawer.getHeight() -
                                             (int) (drawer.getHeight() * slideOffset * 0.3f);
                                     lp.topMargin = (drawer.getHeight() - lp.height) / 2;
                                     contentView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                                 }
                             }
    );

}
```

Comment: this worked for me when I replaced                                    `contentView.setLayoutParams(lp);` with `holderView.setLayoutParams(lp);`

Answer (score 0):

Drawer behavior is a library use Android DrawerLayout Support library as Parent Class [Easy to migrate], that provide an extra behavior on drawer, such as, move view or scaling view's height while drawer on slide.

If current project use Android DrawerLayout Support library and kinda boring with the effect. Then, just change the layout code and calling necessary method for animation/effect.

[Check out github code](https://github.com/shiburagi/Drawer-Behavior)

Gradle

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.infideap.drawerbehavior:drawer-behavior:0.1.5'
}
```

if the gradle unable to sync, you may include this line in project level gradle,

```
repositories {
 maven{
   url "https://dl.bintray.com/infideap2/Drawer-Behavior"
 }
}
```