# Transition with Drawer Layout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I am build an Application which need and image to slide in and out according to the movement of the `DrawerLayout`. Like, When we `open` drawer the image shrinks a little bit and when we `close` the drawer then the image regain its size. 
I have this image in the `Toolbar`.

**My Code :**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/left"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/img"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried doing this by adding the below code

```
mImage.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.animation));
```

in the `onDrawerClosed(View view)` and  `onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)`

But these are not useful as I need to have this animation or transition syncing with the drawer movement.

If Anybody have any suggestions please share.

Comment: Are you just wanting to shrink and grow the image, or move it horizontally, too?

Comment: Actualy I want to shrink and grow the image horizontally

Comment: So, you wanna kinda squeeze it? Same height, but thinner? And no sliding?

Comment: kind of .. I need do it either by shrinking it or by sliding it , because as viewer they are the same

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not sure if I'm quite getting exactly what you want. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37335300). Is it something like that? I'm actually right in the middle of creating a better, more flexible solution for my answer there, so if what you're trying to do is just a little different, lemme know how.

Comment: @MikeM. this is nice but its the layout getting changed not the image i.e, I only need to change an image like that which is in my toolbar

Comment: I'll try this and let know If I stuck somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

Implement `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener` and in `void onDrawerSlide (View drawerView, float slideOffset)` calculate the animation logic.

```
img.animate().scaleX(slideOffset).scaleY(slideOffset);
```

You need to calculate the scale value based on `slideOffset`.
Also, in `void onDrawerClosed (View drawerView)` reset scale to

```
img.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1);
```

Comment: hi, I tried this and this is not exactly what I want . It is just a reverse of that...

Comment: @Atula you need to adjust the slideOffset value. You need to calculate like img.animate().scaleX(1f - slideOffset).scaleY(1f - slideOffset);

Comment: not like the way I want ... it is looking like one page is flipping