# Drawer shadow not getting removed

Tags: android

I am trying to remove  the Drawer shadow when navigation view opens. As suggested in many forums, i have used the below code to remove drawer shadow. But it seems to have no impact.Kindly help me find out where i am going wrong. I am actually trying to achieve the same effect, but when the drawer opens, there seems to be a line/shadow like effect at the end of the drawer.It doesnt look the same as the one in the link. Below is the screenshot of my app. As you can see, there seem to be a line/shadow like effect at the end of the navigation drawer. How can i remove it. I have highlighted the issue in red.
[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP2PI.png)

[Moving and resizing DrawerLayout's content on sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335300/moving-and-resizing-drawerlayouts-content-on-sliding)

```
drawer.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        drawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.END);
```

My XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/navmenu_gradient"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    android:background="@drawable/navmenu_gradient"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NavigationView"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

My OnDrawerSlide method

public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

```
                                               // Scale the View based on current slide offset
                                               final float diffScaledOffset = slideOffset * (1 - END_SCALE);
                                               final float offsetScale = 1 - diffScaledOffset;
                                               contentView.setScaleX(offsetScale);
                                               contentView.setScaleY(offsetScale);

                                               // Translate the View, accounting for the scaled width
                                               final float xOffset = drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset;
                                               final float xOffsetDiff = contentView.getWidth() * diffScaledOffset / 2;
                                               final float xTranslation = xOffset - xOffsetDiff;
                                               contentView.setTranslationX(xTranslation);


                                           }
```

Comment: share your xml.

Comment: share my xml here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the drawer's elevation. So it casts a shadow. You can get rid of it by setting it to 0.

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerElevation(0);
```

or through xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
```

Comment: Thank you @rainmaker, it worked great. By the way is there a way to give that elevation and shadow effect to the content view i.e the layout which occupies around 20 % of the screen in the screenshot i shared

Comment: I mean to say my Main Screen view which we actually translate and animate.  Can i apply elevation and shadow to it

Comment: About the second question, yes you can do it on any layout as you did but put there not 0; but there're some requirements for a layout to cast a shadow, you can read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477371/android-elevation-not-showing-a-shadow/27518160#27518160

Comment: Great it worked! Would you kindly accept the answer?